# Grid view filters fails to search after first search

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2

Grid view with filters by id, name, active. On first search filters works fine but in dev tools console appears error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #w0-filters input, #w0-filters select,
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js?v=1613399435:1560)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.js?v=1613399435:2216)
    at Sizzle.compile (jquery.js?v=1613399435:2610)
    at Sizzle.select (jquery.js?v=1613399435:2700)
    at Sizzle (jquery.js?v=1613399435:862)
    at Function.Sizzle.matchesSelector (jquery.js?v=1613399435:1523)
    at Object.add (jquery.js?v=1613399435:5026)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.js?v=1613399435:4992)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?v=1613399435:367)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js?v=1613399435:202)
```

After that none of the filters work - not sends any query to server.

Gridview:

```
                    if($dataProvider->getTotalCount() >= 20)
                    $layout = '{summary}' . Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'paginationSize',
                            [10 => 10, 20 => 20, 50 => 50, 100 => 100, 200 => 200],
                            ['id' => 'paginationSize', 'class' => 'form-control col-md-1 mb-2']) . "{items}<br/>{pager}";
                else $layout = '{summary}{items}<br/>{pager}';

                echo GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'layout' => $layout,
                    'filterSelector' => $dataProvider->getTotalCount() > 20 ? '#paginationSize' : '',
                    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'columns' => [
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                            'template' => '{view} {copy} {delete}',
                            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '90', 'style' => 'text-align: center;'],
                            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
                            'buttons' => [
                                'copy' => function ($url) {
                                    return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-copy" title="copy"></span>', $url);
                                },
                            ],
                        ],
                        'id',
                        'name',
                        [
                            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
                            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
                            'attribute' => 'active',
                            'filter' => ["1" => "Active", "0" => "Not active"],

                        ],
                        [
                            'attribute' => 'created',
                            'format' =>  ['date', 'HH:mm:ss dd.MM.YYYY'],
                        ],
                        [
                            'attribute' => 'publicated',
                            'format' =>  ['date', 'HH:mm:ss dd.MM.YYYY'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);
```

Controller:

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new NewsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Search model:

```
class NewsSearch extends News
{
    public $paginationSize;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'active'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'paginationSize'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = News::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_DESC]]
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'active' => $this->active,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);

        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = ($this->paginationSize !== null) ? $this->paginationSize : 10;

        return $dataProvider;
    }
    
}
```

There are other CRUD interfaces in this project with filters in gridview which are working fine without described above behaviour. Please help find out what I've made wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was here:

```
'filterSelector' => $dataProvider->getTotalCount() > 20 ? '#paginationSize' : '',
```

filter selector can't be empty string and if its not needed its null by default. Solution is:

```
'filterSelector' => $dataProvider->getTotalCount() > 20 ? '#paginationSize' : null,
```